# Как вывести массив в том порядке, в котором он есть

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например

```
var test = [['1'], ['2'], ['3'],
            ['4'], ['5'], ['6'],
            ['7'], ['8'], ['9']]
```

чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам стоит больше прочитать про многомерные массивы.
Вот статья на русском языке: https://learn.javascript.ru/array
Похоже, Вы немного не так его (массив) оформили.
Пожалуй, попробую угадать то, что Вы на самом деле хотели =)

```
const test = [ //Многомерный массив (двумерный)
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

for(let i = 0; i< test.length; i++) { //Проходимся по первой мерности
    const currentRow = test[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < currentRow.length; j++) { //Проходимся по второй мерности
        const currentCol = currentRow[j];
        console.log(currentCol + ' '); //Выводим текущую "колонку"
    }
    console.log('---'); //Отделяем "строки"
}
```

Comment: Нет, не то что я хотел. У меня есть код на python https://pastebin.com/jC7KcYmY. На самом деле это поле для игры крестики и нолики